# Setting Up 3D Model Visualization in Power BI Desktop

Tags: autodesk-forge

I found this [tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/endymion/v1/developers_guide/setup/). Following the steps provided, I logged into my Autodesk Construction Cloud account to configure the data connector.

However, I am unable to get the project files which I uploaded into ACC. How do I get the files?

Comment: The hyperion-related samples are not maintained anymore, as I know. Please use https://github.com/petrbroz/endymion-next instead.

Answer (score 0):

A person with administrative rights has to go to Insight and set up the extractions for the project.

https://help.autodesk.com/view/DOCS/ENU/?guid=Data_Connector#view-and-run-extractions